# Why $\frac{W}{2P}$ and not $\frac{2P}{W}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve this:

> [image]

I'm a little bit confused, by symmetry, we can draw something like:

> [image]

And $\sin \theta = \frac{O}{H}=\frac{P}{W/2}=\frac{2P}{W}$, no? Perhaps there is some equivalence but it's not clear to me.

Comment: Maybe try solving by moments?

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat I don't know what that is. It wasn't introduced in the book until now.

Comment: The P and W are weights, not distances.  I'm not up on the physics but this is about forces in equilibrium and apparently not geometry at all.

Comment: ... but you are correct.  If the two weights $P$ were hanging down a distance of $p$ and the string is a length of $w$ then $ \sin \theta = \frac p{2w} = \frac W{2P}$ which may be reflect some physical law correlating forces with distances.  It seems plausible.

Answer (score 3):

The vertical component of the force exerted by one of the weights of weight $P$ is $P\sin\theta$, so the two weights between them exert a force of $2P\sin\theta$. So at rest, $W = 2P\sin\theta$, or $\sin\theta = \frac{W}{2P}$. (Note that the horizontal components of the two forces balance, so that $W$ hangs straight down from the middle.)

Comment: Excuse-me for the late response, I've been very busy. I guess I understood it: We decompose $P$ considering a basis with the origin on the point where P is pulled and find that the force on $P$ is the same as the force in the diagonal direction and due to trigonometrical considerations, this force is also $2P \sin \theta$. But then, we have a whole family of identities, isn't it? For example: $W/2=P$, etc?

Comment: I guess [this image](https://i.imgur.com/pjPZvc6.png) will be helpful to better communicate what I mean.

Comment: The arrow you have drawn is *not* $W/2$. The vector $W/2$ would point in the same direction as $W$ but be half as long. So I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: Yes, with $W/2$ I mean that $W/2$ is the norm of that vector and not that it is a multiple of $W$.